# iOS 8's documentContextBeforeInput only returns partial text

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8

I am currently using iOS 8's provided keyboard extension's  `textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput` to get the text that a user has entered in order to perform some sort of modification to it.

I noticed that while the method `documentContextBeforeInput` would work fine for any chucks of texts, as soon as periods "." are inserted, `documentContextBeforeInput` is only able to return text that occurs **after** the period.

For example, testing the following text: "This is sentence 1. And this is sentence 2" When using `documentContextBeforeInput` with placing the cursor at the end, it will only return "And this is sentence 2", and not the entire text that has come before it.

Has anyone also encountered this issue, and if so have you discovered a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't. This is still an issue which ultimately just gets all the words at the end of a sentence.